# What kind of attractor have I obtained?

Tags: chaos-theory

[image]

This is some sort of attractor I have obtained in the digital oscilloscope. The oscilloscope is connected to a chua circuit of my own design. My real question is whether that the phase plot I have obtained on the oscilloscope is a strange attractor or not? Or is it some other attractor?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us a bit more about the oscilloscope image we are seeing here. In particular: How much of the structure we see is attributed to this being a snapshot? Is it changing over time? What appear to be trajectories are not continuous, but a series of dots. Is this an artefact of the measurement? What about the sparse segments in the “background”, e.g., in the top left and bottom right?